# Testing whether a secret value is zero without security bits (in SPDZ)

Tags: multiparty-computation

To test whether a secret value $[x]$ is zero, where $x \in [0,2^{k−1}]$, SPDZ uses the a based on the method of Catrina and de Hoogh [1].

This method requires to working on a field with modulus $p>2^{k+s}$, where $s$ is a is a statistical security parameter.

Does another method exist that perform this comparison but eliminate the need for security bits (performance is not my #1 concern)?

Thanks.

[1]-https://www1.cs.fau.de/filepool/publications/octavian_securescm/smcint-scn10.pdf

Comment: If you want to see whether [x] is zero you can retrieve a random [r] and then Open([x] * [r]). Checking whether [x] > 0 or [x] < 0 it's more complicated and I am not aware of any method computing this without some special preprocessed random bits [b] (using SPDZ).

Answer (score 3):

Secure zero-testing without working in a large field can be done with a protocol by [Lipmaa and Toft](https://kodu.ut.ee/~lipmaa/papers/lt13/improvedEqAndGT.pdf), and with similar efficiency to the Catrina and de Hoogh protocols.

The basic idea is to open $m = x+r \bmod p$, where $r$ is a uniformly random field element and the parties have shares of the bits of $r$.

The parties will test whether $m$ equals $r$ by computing shares of the Hamming distance $[H] = \sum_i (m_i + [r_i] - 2m_i[r_i])$ (which is $\sum m_i \oplus r_i$). Note that $x=0$ iff $H=0$.

They test whether $H = 0$ with a polynomial interpolation trick - this can be done with around $\log p$ multiplications since $H \le \log p$, and most of these can be preprocessed in advance (see Section 3.1 of the paper for the details).

Comment: Didn't know about this method. It seems to me that in order to generate the bit decomposition of [r] in $F_p$ one still needs room for $s$ bits though (as BitDec instruction is implemented now in SPDZ). Am I missing something?

Comment: You just need to do it in reverse - start with $\log p$ random bits, then add them up to get $[r]$. If $p$ is large and close to a power of 2 then $r$ is statistically close to uniform (and if not, just use $s$ extra random bits).